# Omniauth facebook popup callback hash empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, omniauth

I implemented omniauth-facebook with devise and everything worked perfectly. However when I implemented some coffee script (from Railscasts #360) I cannot get the callback to work. As I see it, it call back the controller. But that hash auth. is empty.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? That you very much.

application.html.haml

```
....
-if user_signed_in?
          Logged in as
          = current_user.email
          =link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path
          |
          =link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
        -else
          =link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path
          |
          =link_to 'Log in', new_user_session_path
          |
          = link_to "Log in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), id: "sign_in" 
....
```

facebook.js.coffee.erb

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: '<%= ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"] %>', cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```

routes.rb

```
Hikultura::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"},
    :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" }

  resources :events

  devise_scope :user do match 'auth/facebook/callback', to: 'users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook'
  end

  root :to => 'events#index'
```

users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)

    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable,
  # , :timeoutable and 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :lockable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable

  attr_accessor :current_password

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :current_password, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, 
    :uid, :name, :gender, :town



  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first || User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first

    unless user
      user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                           provider:auth.provider,
                           uid:auth.uid,
                           email:auth.info.email,
                           gender:auth.extra.raw_info.gender,
                           town:auth.extra.raw_info.location,
                           password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                           )
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
    user
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end


end
```

console server log

> NoMethodError (undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass):
>
>   app/models/user.rb:32:in`find_for_facebook_oauth'
>   app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:5:in `facebook'

Comment: What's in the console log ?

Comment: `Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-12 20:15:21 +0100
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (5ms)

Comment: Started GET "/auth/facebook/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-12 20:15:22 +0100
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:19:in `find_for_facebook_oauth'
  app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:5:in `facebook'

Comment: Sorry for the commenting way. I do not know how to format it properly. Hope that was what you meant.

Comment: You could edit your question to put the logs, it would be more readable. Nevermind, the log indicates that in `user.rb`, line 19, you call the method `provider` on an object that is nil. I guess that this object is the `current_user` passed as parameter of `find_for_facebook_oauth` which is nil because the user is not loggued yet.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I edited the question. I understand that the object is nil. The user is in the process of logging in. How can this be fixed?